# Can I subscribe to facebook realtime updates from app settings

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way I can subscribe to facebook real time updates from my app settings rather than programmatically using facebook API?

Thanks,
Kirthi

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can only do it using the API